# How to Increase TableCell Height When Content Added Programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I am Developing an app. I have some data which is coming from server.

Now I Have no Idea about the data count for rows. I only Know the name of Fields.

I want To show these data in `UITableViewCell`.

I have a custom `TableCell`. I have taken a `ContentView` inside it.
I have set the following constraint:

```
     - Leading
     - Trailing 
     - Top
     - Bottom
```

[image]
In My `ViewController's` DidLoad Method I have this Code:

```
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:cellName bundle:nil];
   [[self mTableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:cellName];


     self.mTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.mTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0;
```

I am creating `UILabel` Like this

```
      - (void)awakeFromNib {
[super awakeFromNib];


CGFloat ypos = 0;

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    UILabel *lbl  = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    lbl.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];
    lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0,ypos,30,10);

    [self addSubview:lbl];
    ypos += 16;
}

[self setNeedsLayout];
[self layoutIfNeeded];

// Initialization code
}
```

This is my CustomCell.But my TableCell Hegiht is not Increasing.

Please anyone suggest me what is i am missing ?

Comment: where are contentView(i hope you are talking about your UIView subclass added to cell's content view) constraints. ?

Comment: you need to set constrain for labels and set numbersOfLine is zero. It will increase the label height automatically.

Comment: @vikash1307 Bro I am creating them Programatically

Comment: then also, you can do bro.

Comment: please check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235605/is-it-possible-to-have-differing-heights-in-a-uitableview-cell-when-i-use-severa/37236303#37236303

Comment: "TableCell Hegiht is not Increasing" - be more specific , i mean have you looged it, is your content view height increasing but not cell ?

Comment: You need to add the labels with auto layout constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *dict1 = (NSDictionary*)[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellText = [dict1 valueForKey:@"test"];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME_GOTHAM_4 size:11.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    return labelSize.height + 80;
}
```

Comment: what this code does ?  sizeWithFont: is now deprecated.

Comment: this is my last hope..I dont want to make code bulky that's why i am searching for better way. Thanks for this solution

Answer (score -1):

You are doing right, so far. But do not forget to use the delegate/data source of your tableView - **cellForRowHeight**.

Also, as Lion have mentioned, you need to add constraints to your labels. If you do your label programmatically, then do the autolayout programmatically as well.