# How to dynamic cell height with Parse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dynamic

Here is my storyboard: [image]

The method i use to get the image is:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

     cell.mainImage.file = (PFFile *)object[@"image"];
    [cell.mainImage loadInBackground];
}
```

Row Height is set as:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       return 501.0f;
}
```

I also would like to have the Image to be filled perfectly, much like instagram. I dont want images to have bars on the top and bottom.

Comment: have you tried this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights?rq=1

Comment: yeah ive seen that, ill give it another try.

Comment: my solution is here you can have look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235605/is-it-possible-to-have-differing-heights-in-a-uitableview-cell-when-i-use-severa/37236303#37236303

Answer (score 2):

this was work for me

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: Did you have a UIImageView in the storyboard or did you create it in cellForRow?

Comment: i have image in cell in storyboard with auto layout

Comment: with the image in storyboard, how do you have the autolayout set up so that the image can resize? i dont want to have borders